# How to update the SharePoint list form access?

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, lookup-column, access

I have a SharePoint list with Lookup columns and metadata(Content type) fields.

I opened the list in Access When I was trying to add new data or edit the data it's saying

> "can not update database or object is read-only access".

How to update this list?

Answer (score 1):

This error is a known issue in Microsoft Access that occurs when a table is linked to a SharePoint list that has hidden metadata.

All details are described at ["Cannot update. Database or object is read-only error in linked SharePoint list in Access"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3200680/-cannot-update.-database-or-object-is-read-only-error-in-linked-sharepoint-list-in-access)

To overcome this issue try to apply the below instructions:

1. Link all the lookup columns in the underlying list to tables. as mentioned at [“Cannot update. Database or object is read-only”](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3200677/-cannot-update.-database-or-object-is-read-only-error-in-a-query-against-a-linked-sharepoint-view-if-there-are-unlinked-lookup-fields-in-access)
2. Disable caching in Access. To do this, follow these steps:

   - In Access, select File > Options.
   - Select Current Database.
   - Scroll down to the Caching Web Service area, and then locate the Microsoft SharePoint tables.
   - Select the Never Cache check box.
3. Or try to re-create the list without the metadata columns.

Comment: i followed these steps but still not able to update the list, SharePoint list having hidden metadata columns.So its not possible to update the list from access ?